# Why is emitting an event considered as state-changing?

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat

I put an `emit Event(uint256 value)` inside a function with `view`. But I got the below compile error by using `npx hardhat compile`:

```
TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.
```

I wonder why emitting an event is considered as a state change as it's not really touching the internal state of the contract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Events don't change the state of the contract where they are emitted but they change the state of the whole blockchain.

In simple terms, a log (emitting an event) will make a change in the **Transaction Receipts Root** that is recorded in the header of a block and a adding new block is considered a change in the state of the blockchain.